# How do I enumerate all top level windows in Windows 10 using PyWinAuto

Tags: python, windows-10, pywinauto

I've never used pywinauto before, but I'm trying to get a list of all the top-level windows (all the windows with icons in the toolbar). However, when I use PyWinAuto's findiwndows.enum_windows() function, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pywinauto

def main():
    windows = pywinauto.findwindows.enum_windows()
    print([w.window_text() for w in windows])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
  File "MuteApplication_Script.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "MuteApplication_Script.py", line 31, in main
    windows = pywinauto.findwindows.enum_windows()
  File "C:\Users\Merrick Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 368, in enum_windows
    win32functions.EnumWindows(proc, 0)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected WinFunctionType instance instead of WinFunctionType
```

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong usage of low level module. High level interface should start with `Application` or `Desktop` object as described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) (chapter "Entry Points for Automation").

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
print([w.window_text() for w in windows])
```

`windows` is a list of high level wrappers around all top level windows that contains method `.window_text()`.

Module `findwindows` was left for backward compatibility with old `backend="win32"` which is default for `Desktop()` or `Application()` instance. This module will be removed in next major release.